# Export functionality in embedded pivot4j report

Tags: pentaho-cde, pivot4j

I am embedding a pivot4j report using pivot4j component in pentaho.

Is it possible to have a export to excel OR PDF facility like it has while designing the report?

If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution from the developers. Posting as it is from the URL https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pivot4j-list/WQ91bXbOdbs/K_eW6VZqAwAJ

> It's something doable but it will require a bit of custom modification
>   of the view template. When you embed a Pivot4J report, embed.xhtml is
>   used as the view template instead of view.xhtml. If you compare them
>   with each other, you can that the former is just a minimal version of
>   the latter.
>
> So you can probably copy the necessary components related to the
>   export feature (look for 'mi-export-*') and paste into the embeded
>   template and modify it if necessary.